# How to make an MP3 player transmitter for wireless headphones?

Tags: mp3, bluetooth, wireless

*(Click on images to see their full resolution).*

**I am trying to know if an MP3 can be a transmitter for wireless headphones.**

The MP3 is a Sony one (I don't have the model but these photos can help):

[image: MP3 1]

[image: MP3 2]

[image: MP3 3]

[image: MP3 4]

[image: MP3 5]

[image: MP3 6]

The wireless headphones that I am using are Noga Twins 2:

[image: Wireless headphones]

I searched and concluded that the MP3 has no Bluetooth, so, trying to imitate a smartphone that has Bluetooth, I was not able to connect the MP3 and headphones to listen to music.

I have watched the YouTube video

[[image: Video thumbnail]Add Bluetooth to your MP3 Player With a Bluetooth Transmitter](https://youtu.be/g50zHOb6quI)

but **I am looking for an software/app/program-based-solution** i.e., putting an e.g. executable file into my MP3 via USB connection to my computer that imitates a Bluetooth transmitter. I couldn't find any software solution.

**Is it possible to do that?**

Comment: Sorry, but how should software be able to create the required circuits (antenna etc) for that? You'll need hardware to do that. And that's outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Izzy thank you for your comment! That's why I ask; I wanted to know if there was a program that imitates Bluetooth. Thank you again.

Comment: Short 2 letter answer: No. Technically impossible.